# c# Command /o blacklist username reason

Tags: c#

I'm working at a chat program and i want to add for users a command like "/o blacklist hisUsername andReason". So let's say user1 added in blacklist user2 because he talk in another language. When user2 send a message all users receive the message exept user1. The command work but at reason program add only first word. Here is the code:

```
MainForm mf = new MainForm();
string[] command = Text.Split(' ');
command[0] = command[0].ToLower();
if(textBox3.Text.Contains("blacklist"))
{
    string Username = Text.Remove(0, command[0].Length + command[1].Length + 2);
    using (TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(mf.Database + "\\" + mf.BlackList + "\\" + command[1] + ".txt"))
    {
        tw.Write(command[2].ToString());
        messagesChat.Text += command[1] + " was added in BlackList!";
    }
}
```

Database is a directory named Files
BlackList is a directory named BlackList

So after this command program will create a file in Files/BlackList/ His username, but when the file is created program add only first word.

Comment: You don't give out enough code. What is `command`?

Comment: Oh yes :/ sorry.. I will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

As a debugger would show you, you're writing only the third word to the file. You either have to tell `Split()` to only split at maximum three parts or take the original text and take from there the whole reason.

You put the reason into `Username` and don't save that. Maybe rename the variable so it isn't misleading and use it instead of `command[2]`

Comment: Can you post code please? I'm romanian and i don't understand english very good :(

Comment: Still don't understand :/